# Flutter Multi-select via Autocomplete - preserve user input

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete, multi-select

I am trying to make essentially a Flutter multi-select input with an auto-complete search box, and I'm attempting to use the Material [Autocomplete](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html) class with a custom `User` type to do so. The behavior I am after but having trouble with is for the text input to remain unchanged, even as the user makes selections.

What's making this a bit difficult is the `displayStringForOption` property. This property only takes the instance of the custom type corresponding to the user's selection, and as far as I can tell, nothing that indicates what the current text input is. This causes the input to be overwritten when the user makes a selection, which I would like to avoid. I don't believe the `TextEditingController` is available either.
Here's an example of what I have at the moment:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
    Autocomplete<User>(
      fieldViewBuilder: _inviteeSearchInput,
      displayStringForOption: (u) => '${u.name} - ${u.email}', // <== actually want this to just remain as the user's input
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
          return widget.availableUsers.where((user) => !_selectedUsers.contains(user));
        }
        return widget.availableUsers.where((User u) =>
          !_selectedUsers.contains(u) && (u.name.toLowerCase().contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase()) ||
              u.email.toLowerCase().contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase())));
      },
      optionsViewBuilder: ...,
      onSelected: (u) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedUsers = { ..._selectedUsers, u };
        });
      },
    );

  Widget _inviteeSearchInput(
      BuildContext context,
      TextEditingController textEditingController,
      FocusNode focusNode,
      VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted,
  ) => TextFormField(
    controller: textEditingController, // <== the TextEditingController is here, but I don't think that helps?
    focusNode: focusNode,
    decoration: ...
  );
```

One thought I've tried that seems to work, but for some reason doesn't feel right is to keep track of the user input in a variable and update it with the `onChanged` property of the `fieldViewBuilder`:

```dart
class MultiSelectAutoCompleteState extends State<MultiSelectAutoComplete> {
  Set<User> _selectedUsers = {};
  String inputVal = ''; // <== var to keep track of user's input
  
  // ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
    Autocomplete<User>(
      fieldViewBuilder: _inviteeSearchInput,
      displayStringForOption: (u) => inputVal, // <== using that as the display string
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
          return widget.availableUsers.where((user) => !_selectedUsers.contains(user));
        }
        return widget.availableUsers.where((User u) =>
          !_selectedUsers.contains(u) && (u.name.toLowerCase().contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase()) ||
              u.email.toLowerCase().contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase())));
      },
      optionsViewBuilder: ...,
      onSelected: (u) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedUsers = { ..._selectedUsers, u };
        });
      },
    );

  Widget _inviteeSearchInput(
      BuildContext context,
      TextEditingController textEditingController,
      FocusNode focusNode,
      VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted,
  ) => TextFormField(
    controller: textEditingController,
    onChanged: (s) => inputVal = s, // <== setting the var here
    focusNode: focusNode,
    decoration: ...
  );
```

I'm not calling `setState` in the `onChanged` callback because I'm not sure I want to trigger a rebuild every time the input changes, but maybe I do?

I'm curious if there's a better way to do this, for some reason, this feels icky to me, and I'm also having a hard time reasoning about whether or not I want to call `setState` in the `onChanged` callback if I do go with the second option.

Comment: Did you manage to come up with a widget? I hate the fact that the framework itself does not provide this kind of widget. :(

Comment: Unfortunately not. I did find this package though that ended up being flexible enough for me: https://github.com/esentis/multiple_search_selection

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputChip-class.html#material.InputChip.2
check this out